# How to count members with jsonpath?

Tags: java, spring, testing, jsonpath, spring-test-mvc

Is it possible to count the number of members using JsonPath?

Using [Spring MVC test](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc) I'm testing a controller that generates

```json
{"foo": "oof", "bar": "rab"}
```

with:

```java
standaloneSetup(new FooController(fooService)).build()
    .perform(get("/something").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.foo").value("oof"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.bar").value("rab"));
```

I'd like to make sure that no other members are present in the generated json. Hopefully by counting them using jsonPath. Is it possible? Alternate solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

To test size of **array**: `jsonPath("$", hasSize(4))`

To count members of **object**: `jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(4))`

---

I.e. to test that API returns an **array** of 4 items:

accepted value: `[1,2,3,4]`

```
mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(4)));
```

---

to test that API returns an **object** containing 2 members:

accepted value: `{"foo": "oof", "bar": "rab"}`

```
mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(2)));
```

---

I'm using Hamcrest version 1.3 and Spring Test 3.2.5.RELEASE

[hasSize(int) javadoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasSize(int))

Note:
You need to include hamcrest-library dependency and `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;` for hasSize() to work.

Comment: @mattb - if using Maven, do not add `hamcrest-all` as a dependancy, but use `hamcrest-library`: https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/HamcrestDistributables

Comment: What if one does not know the size and wants to get it?

Comment: @menuka-ishan - I don't think it's deprecated, according to: [MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#jsonPath-java.lang.String-org.hamcrest.Matcher-) javadoc

Comment: @zygimantus you must count up the size of all the fields on your Object/Array, either from source code or web browser developer tools inspection of the response.

Comment: For kotlin you may need to add type argument like so: `.andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize<Array<Any>>(4)))`

Answer (score 29):

You can also use the methods inside the jsonpath, so instead of

```
mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL))
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(2)));
```

you can do

```
mockMvc.perform(get(API_URL))
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.length()", is(2)));
```

Answer (score 13):

We can use [JsonPath functions](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) like `size()` or `length()`, like this:

```
@Test
public void givenJson_whenGetLengthWithJsonPath_thenGetLength() {
    String jsonString = "{'username':'jhon.user','email':'jhon@company.com','age':'28'}";

    int length = JsonPath
        .parse(jsonString)
        .read("$.length()");

    assertThat(length).isEqualTo(3);
}
```

Or simply parsing to `net.minidev.json.JSONObject` and get the size:

```
@Test
public void givenJson_whenParseObject_thenGetSize() {
    String jsonString = "{'username':'jhon.user','email':'jhon@company.com','age':'28'}";

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonString);

    assertThat(jsonObject)
        .size()
        .isEqualTo(3);
}
```

Indeed, the second approach looks to perform better than the first one. I made a JMH (Java Microbenchmark Harness) performance test and I get the following results:

```
| Benchmark                                       | Mode  | Cnt | Score       | Error        | Units |
|-------------------------------------------------|-------|-----|-------------|--------------|-------|
| JsonPathBenchmark.benchmarkJSONObjectParse      | thrpt | 5   | 3241471.044 | ±1718855.506 | ops/s |
| JsonPathBenchmark.benchmarkJsonPathObjectLength | thrpt | 5   | 1680492.243 | ±132492.697  | ops/s |
```

The example code can be found [here](https://github.com/earth001/jsonpath-jmh-test).

Comment: JMH? What does this stand for?

Comment: JMH means 
Java Microbenchmark Harness, see https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

Answer (score 4):

Been dealing with this myself today. It doesn't seem like this is implemented in the available assertions. However, there is a method to pass in an `org.hamcrest.Matcher` object. With that you can do something like the following:

```
final int count = 4; // expected count

jsonPath("$").value(new BaseMatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof JSONObject && ((JSONObject) obj).size() == count;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        // nothing for now
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried with [WebTestClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html) similar approach:

```
webTestClient.get()
    .uri(KEYS_MANAGEMENT_URI)
    .header(
        HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
        createBearerToken(createJwtClaims(KEYS_AUTHORITY_VIEW))
    )
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().isOk()
    .expectBody()
    .jsonPath("data").isArray()
    .jsonPath("data.length()").isEqualTo(1)
    .jsonPath("data[0].id").isEqualTo(KEY_ID)
```

And assertions worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have `com.jayway.jsonassert.JsonAssert` on your classpath (which was the case with me), testing in the following way may be a possible workaround:

```
assertEquals(expectedLength, ((net.minidev.json.JSONArray)parsedContent.read("$")).size());
```

*[note: i assumed that the content of the json is always an array]*

Answer (score 0):

For those, who use Kotlin: `org.hamcrest.Matchers#is(T)` will help you.
Here is an example, if your root json element is array:

```json
[
  {
    "someProperty": "someValue"
  },
  {
    "someProperty": "someValue"
  }
]
```

```kotlin
mvc.get("/your-endpoint")
            .andExpect {
                status { isOk() }
                content { contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) }
                content {
                    jsonPath("$.length()", `is`(2))
                }
            }
```