# How to verify in JMeter that specific variable set by JDBC Request is higher than 0?

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I created JMeter test when I use JDCB query which returns NUMBER value which I set to variable e.g. called employeeID.

I know that it is possible to use Response Assertion and I can verify if my variable: employeeID_1 is equal to specific expected value.

How can I verify if my variable is > 0 instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight forward would be using BeanShell Assertion like this:

```
int myNumber = -1;

try {
    myNumber = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("employeeID_1"));
} catch(NumberFormatException e)
{ /* Continue to verification with default value */ }

if(myNumber <= 0) {
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Expected value to be above 0, but got " + myNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not the components purpose I used the [`Size Assertion`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion) component by using the `JMeter variable` field and the `>` option with the value `0`. So far I haven't found a reason why not to use this component for testing variables.

[image: Size Assertion]