# Spring MVC Test with Hamcrest and JsonPath: How count the body size? (not count members)

Tags: json, hamcrest, spring-test-mvc

I am working with:

- Spring MVC Test
- Hamcrest
- JsonPath

I have the following how a response from the server:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {
  "id" : "100",
  "nombre" : "Jesús Você",
  "apellido" : "Mão Nuñez",
  "fecha" : "1977-12-08"
}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
```

The following works as expected (is valid):

```
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$").exists())
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$", notNullValue()))
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$", isA(LinkedHashMap.class)))

 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*").exists())
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", notNullValue()))
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", isA(JSONArray.class)))
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(is(4))))
```

I need test that `("$")` is 1. Confirm exists 1 item. It to confirm again the following:

```
Body = {
      "id" : "100",
      "nombre" : "Jesús Você",
      "apellido" : "Mão Nuñez",
      "fecha" : "1977-12-08"
    }
```

I've tried:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(is(1))))
```

Observe the difference between `$` and `$.*`, for the latter I know it counts the number of fields. But from the former I always get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$"
Expected: a collection with size is <1>
     but: was <{id=100, nombre=Jesús Você, apellido=Mão Nuñez, fecha=1977-12-08}>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:18
```

'Seems' the data is not a collection, but remember that `.andExpect(jsonPath("$", isA(LinkedHashMap.class)))` pass. I am confused in someway.

Therefore is possible test that `("$")` is 1.? If yes, how?.

I've read [count members with jsonpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745332/count-members-with-jsonpath)

And says:

> To test size of array: jsonPath("$", hasSize(4))
>
> To count members of object: jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(4))

My data returned is not an array, it is a `LinkedHashMap.class` because if I use `.andExpect(jsonPath("$").isArray())` I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected an array at JSON path "$" but found: {id=100, nombre=Jesús Você, apellido=Mão Nuñez, fecha=1977-12-08}
Expected: an instance of java.util.List
     but: <{id=100, nombre=Jesús Você, apellido=Mão Nuñez, fecha=1977-12-08}> is a java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

BTW: `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.*").isArray())` pass.

Comment: _I need test that ("$") is 1. Confirm exists 1 item._ I've re-read this a few times but stil can't understand it. What does `1` exactly mean here?

Comment: The following `Body = {
      "id" : "100",
      "nombre" : "Jesús Você",
      "apellido" : "Mão Nuñez",
      "fecha" : "1977-12-08"
    }` is just one item with four fields. Therefore `$.*` represents the item with four fields. But I need to test the item (I thought `$` should be enough but fails).

Comment: Hm, but what's wrong with `jsonPath("$").exists()` then?

Comment: Is valid, just curios if is possible in the other way. What happens if the result returns two items. `jsonPath("$").exists()` should pass too but It does not care if was 1 or 2 items.

Comment: But how do you get more than two JSON items as the root at once? It should fail due to a syntax error or whatever else reason, but this must be illegal anyway.

Comment: Yes, should fail because is not an array (I have just one item). Remember `To test size of array: jsonPath("$", hasSize(4))` pass when is an array with many items, in this case 4.

Comment: It must be specifics of the `hasSize()` matcher which seems to accept both root arrays or root array elements expression. You can write your matcher to substitute `hasSize()`. Sorry, I'm still blind to see the rationale behind your request. :)

Comment: That's the point `accept both root arrays or root array ` for the latter or `root array` the `hasSize()` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

To validate the size of a **Map** instead of:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
```

you should use:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$", aMapWithSize(1)))
```

**Note**: Check this [link](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#aMapWithSize-int-) with org.hamcrest.Matchers javadoc

Comment: Where is declared `aMapWithSize`? Your link does not include it

Comment: @Manuel Jordan, I looked and found this: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/collection/IsMapWithSize.html#aMapWithSize-int-

Comment: @alfonsosolis consider to update the "Note" part is not clear - thanks for the link @D.Kastier!

Comment: I updated the link ... ManuelJordan and @D.Kastier thanks for pointing it out