# WebTestClient assertThat json has only specific keys

Tags: java, json, junit-jupiter, spring-webtestclient

I'm testing my endpoints like so:

```
        webTestClient.get().uri(BASE_URL).
            .exchange().expectStatus().isOk().expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.name").isEqualTo("test1")
            .jsonPath("$.street").isEqualTo("test1")
            .jsonPath("$.id").isEqualTo(1);
```

Is there any way I can make sure that the json has only those 3 fields and not more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by checking the size of the json properties. Not exactly what I wanted (because now I have to change 2 values of something changes), but it's still a viable solution:

```
.jsonPath("$.length()").isEqualTo(4);
```

Hamcrest Matchers did not work for me.

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195945/3824715